# How to revert Open Quickly back to dark theme on Xcode 9.3?

Tags: xcode, xcode9.3

I've just updated Xcode to 9.3 and I've noticed that "Open Quickly" ( <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) interface have reverted to white theme (instead of black on previous versions, which obeyed my Mac's color theme, which is dark):

[image]

My Mac's theme is the dark theme and, for example, Spotlight Search obeys it:

[image]

Xcode's Open Quickly was also dark like Spotlight Search too, until I updated. Why would have it turned to light theme and how do I make it obey the system theme again?

Comment: Why? Because Apple giveth, and Apple taketh away...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as seen on WWDC 2018, it is coming back with the whole Dark Mode theme on the new macOS.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no easy way to get back the dark theme. It's *possible*, but it involves unsigning Xcode and byte patching the `DVTKit` binary that's in the Xcode bundle. I wrote [a blog post](http://ndersson.me/post/byte_patching_xcode/) about this a few days ago. In summary, to get back the dark Open Quickly theme in Xcode 9.3*, perform the following steps (at your own risk):

1. Download [Hex Fiend](https://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/)
2. Open `Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit` in Hex Fiend.
3. Navigate to adress `0x00000000000163cd` using Edit > Jump to Offset.
4. Replace the byte right after the insertion point that says `31` with `09`.
5. Save.
6. Download [unsign](https://github.com/steakknife/unsign) and follow the installation instructions.
7. Unsign the Xcode binary using `$ unsign Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`. This will produce a new binary.
8. Replace the signed Xcode binary with the unsigned binary using `$ mv Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode.unsigned Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`
9. Launch Xcode and revel in the return of the dark Open Quickly theme.

** Only tested on Xcode 9.3 (9E145) downloaded from the Apple Developer Portal*

With that said, it's probably not worth the effort :-) Since the dark theme is still there (but disabled) I would expect it to return in one of the next Xcode releases. It might even be there in the Xcode 9.4 beta (I haven't tried it yet).

Comment: Wow, even though I don't think it's currently worth the effort for me, I absolutely *loved* reading the whole blog post :)